# Regex string match in c#

Tags: c#, regex, formatting

So, I'd like to check if a string of letters and digits is in correct format

Here's what it needs to look like:

```
123abc#456def#
```

I've tried something like that:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]#)([0-9a-zA-Z]#)$");
```

Didn't help me...

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}` You need to quantify your sets.

Comment: You should consider clarifying the requirements - from your example I would infer it's "three digits followed by three lowercase alpha characters" etc..  but there's room for error in inference..  Is it always 3 of each?  Are uppercase characters allowed?  Going through the mental gymnastics to adequately describe the regex requirements may also help you to have an "aha!" as you write the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

As I mentioned in the comments you need to quantify your sets as such: `[0-9a-zA-Z]{6}`

### Code

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]{6}#)([0-9a-zA-Z]{6}#)$
```

You can also do `^([0-9a-zA-Z]{6}#){2}$` since .net keeps multiple captures (not just the last one). See this shorter regex in use [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%7b6%7d%23%29%7b2%7d%24&i=123abc%23456def%23). Click on Table and under the heading `$1` expand `2 captures`

For ensuring 3 numbers followed by 3 letters use either of the following patterns:

```
^(\d{3}[a-z]{3}#)(\d{3}[a-z]{3}#)$
^(\d{3}[a-z]{3}#){2}$
```

And add [`IgnoreCase` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.ignorecase?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the following regex:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{6}#){2}$
```

But you didn't specify the format of your strings, so It's actually a guess game. Are those hash-delimited groups only recurring two times? Do you want to match 3 numbers followed by 3 letters in each group?